# println a sentence once in Processing

Tags: processing, println

I'm wondering how to println a sentence ONCE in Processing. when I type `println("Hello World!");` it just shows lots of Hello World! sentences.  I know how to fix it with keyPressed (when the key is pressed, type this, and stuff)  but I don't know how to do it in a simple way...

Comment: doesnt really matter... i just found out that you just can do println(blah blah blah); ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag so that it only gets printed once.  For example, at global scope you should have:

```
 bool did_print = false;
```

And where you do the println:

```
 if(!did_print)  {
      println("Hello World!");
      did_print = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is in a loop (which it sounds like). I would go with either what Mikola said or:

```
while(someVar == whatever) {
    // some code
    println("Hello World!");
    break;
}
```

The key being the `breaK;` statement to fall out of the loop.

If it's not in a loop, or this doesn't help, please expand on the issue..